# If $x>0$we have $(1+x^2)f'(x)+(1+x)f(x)=1$ and $g'(x)=f(x), f(0)=g(0)=0$Prove:

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, power-series

If $x>0$ we have $(1+x^2)f'(x)+(1+x)f(x)=1$. And $g'(x)=f(x), f(0)=g(0)=0$

Prove that:$\displaystyle \frac14<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g(\frac1n)<1$

I tried solving the ODE,But it seems very complex.and I still have no idea about it.Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen this question here before (I think the question got deleted). Do you mind telling where it comes from?

Comment: Oh,Someone asked me..he said It comes from a paper of an university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can prove that
$0.255...
\le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} g(\frac1{n})
\le 0.3898...
$.

(added later)

A more accurate computation gives
$0.268...
\le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} g(\frac1{n})
\le 0.30937...
$.

This added to
Marcin Malogrosz's result
for $g(1)$
*does* give a sum below 1.

I'm working on that last
$g(1)$.
If I get it,
I'll update this answer.
(Marcin Malogrosz's result
renders this unnecessary.)

---

We are given
$(1+x^2)f'(x)+(1+x)f(x)
=1,
f(0) = 0
$.
Since
$f'(x)
=\frac{1-(1+x)f(x)}{1+x^2}
$,
by repeatedly differentiating this,
$f(x)$
has derivatives of all orders.

Let
$f(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$
with
$a_0 = 0$.

$\begin{array}\\
(1+x)f(x)
&=f(x)+xf(x)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n-1} x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n-1} x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n+a_{n-1}) x^n\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_nx^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}\\
&=a_1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
x^2f'(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n+2}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Combining all of these,

$\begin{array}\\
1
&=(1+x^2)f'(x)+(1+x)f(x)\\
&=a_1+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 
(a_n+a_{n-1}+(n+1)a_{n+1}+(n-1)a_{n-1})x^{n}\\
&=a_1+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 
(a_n+(n+1)a_{n+1}+na_{n-1})x^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Equating coefficients,
$a_1 = 1$
and,
for $n \ge 1$,
$0
= a_n+(n+1)a_{n+1}+na_{n-1}
$
or
$a_{n+1}
=-\frac{a_n+na_{n-1}}{n+1}
$.

From this,
if
$|a_n| \le c$
and
$|a_{n-1}| \le c$,
then
$|a_{n+1}| \le c$.
Therefore
$|a_n| \le 1$
for $n \ge 1$.

Therefore,
since $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
(n=1)&: a_2 
= -\frac{a_1+a_0}{2}
= -\frac{1}{2}\\
(n=2)&: a_3 
= -\frac{a_2+2a_1}{3}
= -\frac{-\frac12+2}{3}
= -\frac{1}{2}
\\
(n=3)&: a_4 
= -\frac{a_3+3a_2}{4}
= -\frac{-\frac12+3(-\frac12)}{4}
= \frac{1}{2}
\\
(n=4)&: a_5 
= -\frac{a_4+4a_3}{5}
= -\frac{\frac12+4(-\frac12)}{5}
= \frac{3}{10}
\\
\end{array}
$

From these,
$|a_n| \le \frac12$
for $n \ge 2$.
Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
|f(x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}|
&=|\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} a_n x^n|\\
&\le\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} |a_n| x^n\\
&\le\frac12\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}  x^n\\
&=\frac{x^3}{2(1-x)}\\
&\le x^3
\qquad\text{for }0 \le x \le \frac12\\
\end{array}
$

Integrating this
from $0$ to $u$,
since
$g(u)
=\int_0^u f(x) dx
$,
$|g(u)-\frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{u^3}{6}|
\le \frac{u^4}{4} 
$.

Looking at this,
we can take one fewer term
in the expansion.
This becomes

$\begin{array}\\
|f(x)-x|
&=|\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n x^n|\\
&\le\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} |a_n| x^n\\
&\le\frac12\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}  x^n\\
&=\frac{x^2}{2(1-x)}\\
&\le x^2
\qquad\text{for }0 \le x \le \frac12\\
\end{array}
$

Integrating this
from $0$ to $u$,
since
$g(u)
=\int_0^u f(x) dx
$,
$|g(u)-\frac{u^2}{2}|
\le \frac{u^3}{3} 
$.

Therefore,
for $n \ge 2$,
$|g(\frac1{n})-\frac1{2n^2}|
\le \frac1{3n^3}
$
or
$\frac1{2n^2}-\frac1{3n^3}
\le g(\frac1{n})
\le \frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}
$.

Summing this from $2$ to $\infty$,
$\frac12(\zeta(2)-1)-\frac13(\zeta(3)-1)
\le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} g(\frac1{n})
\le \frac12(\zeta(2)-1)+\frac13(\zeta(3)-1)
$
or
$0.255...
\le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} g(\frac1{n})
\le 0.3898...
$.

If we use the more accurate
$|g(u)-\frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{u^3}{6}|
\le \frac{u^4}{4} 
$,
$|g(\frac1{n})-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac{1}{6n^3}|
\le \frac1{4n^4}
$
or
$\frac1{2n^2}-\frac{1}{6n^3}- \frac1{4n^4}
\le g(\frac1{n})
\le \frac1{2n^2}-\frac{1}{6n^3}+ \frac1{4n^4}
$.

Summing this from $2$ to $\infty$,
$\frac12(\zeta(2)-1)-\frac16(\zeta(3)-1)-\frac14(\zeta(4)-1)
\le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} g(\frac1{n})
\le \frac12(\zeta(2)-1)+\frac16(\zeta(3)-1)+\frac14(\zeta(4)-1)
$
or
$0.268...
\le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} g(\frac1{n})
\le 0.30937...
$.

This added to
Marcin Malogrosz's result
for $g(1)$
*does* give a sum below 1.

Comment: It's very useful! I 'm waiting for your g(1)!

Comment: See Marcin Malogrosz's answer. Though I would have to refine mine to get the sum below 1.

Answer (score 2):

Using integrating factor $m$ we first solve given ODE:
\begin{align*}
f'+\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}f&=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\\
m'&=m\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}\\
(\ln(m))'&=\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}\\
\ln(m)&=\int_0^x\frac{1+y}{1+y^2}dy=arctg(x)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{1+x^2}\frac{1}{z}dz=arctg(x)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2)\\
m&=\exp(arctg(x))+\sqrt{1+x^2}\\
f&=\frac{1}{m}\int_0^x\frac{m}{1+y^2}dy=\frac{1}{m}\Big(\int_0^xarctg'(y)\exp(arctg(y))dy+\int_0^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}dy\Big)=\frac{1}{m}\Big(\exp(arctg(x))-1+\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\Big)
\end{align*}
Thus
\begin{align*}
g(x)&=\int_0^xf(y)dy=\int_0^x\frac{\exp(arctg(y))-1+\ln(y+\sqrt{1+y^2})}{\exp(arctg(y))+\sqrt{1+y^2}}dy
\end{align*}
Using monotonicity of $f$ we get that
\begin{align*}
g(1)&\leq\int_0^1\frac{\exp(arctg(1))-1+\ln(1+\sqrt{1+1^2})}{\exp(arctg(1))+\sqrt{1+1^2}}dy=\frac{\exp(\pi/4)-1+\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}{\exp(\pi/4)+\sqrt{2}}<0,575
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice. But this added to my upper bound is a little above 1. Maybe I should try for a more accurate upper bound, using more terms of the apprximation.

Comment: I used a more accurate approximation and now the sum of yours and mine *is* below 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start.
It's midnight,
so I am stopping
with what I have.

$g(x)
=g(0) + \int_0^x f(t) dt
=\int_0^x f(t) dt
$.

Therefore
$g(1/n)
=\int_0^{1/n} f(t) dt
$.

Since
$(1+x^2)f'(x)+(1+x)f(x)
=1
$,
$f(x)
=\frac1{1+x}-f'(x)\frac{1+x^2}{1+x}
$.

Since
$(\frac{1+x^2}{1+x})'
=1-\frac{2}{(1+x)^2}
$,
$h(x)
=\frac{1+x^2}{1+x}$
is decreasing for
$0 \le x 
< \sqrt{2}-1
$.
Therefore
$1 \ge h(x)
\ge h(\sqrt{2}-1)
=\frac{1+(2-2\sqrt{2}+1)}{\sqrt{2}}
=\frac{4-2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}
=2\sqrt{2}-2
=c
\approx .818
$.

Therefore
$f'(x) \ge f'(x)h(x) \ge c f'(x)
$
so
$\int_0^{1/n} f'(x) \ge \int_0^{1/n} f'(x)h(x)
\ge c \int_0^{1/n} f'(x)
$
or
$f(1/n)
\ge \int_0^{1/n} f'(x)h(x)
\ge c f(1/n)
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
g(1/n)
&=\int_0^{1/n} f(t)dt \\
&=\int_0^{1/n}dt(\frac1{1+t}-f'(t)h(t))\\
&=\int_0^{1/n}\frac{dt}{1+t}-\int_0^{1/n}f'(t)h(t)dt\\
&=\ln(1+1/n)-\int_0^{1/n}f'(t)h(t)dt\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$cf(1/n)
\le \ln(1+1/n)-g(1/n)
\le f(1/n)
$.

So,
if we can get bounds for
$f(1/n)$,
we can sum them
to get what we want.

$f'(0) = 1$.

Differentiating
$(1+x^2)f'(x)+(1+x)f(x)
=1
$,
$0
=(1+x^2)f''+2x f' + f(x)+(1+x)f'
$,
or
$(1+x^2)f''
=-f-(1+3x)f'
$.
Therefore
$f''(0) = -1
$.

For small $x$,
$f(x)
\approx x-x^2/2
$
so
$f(1/n)
\approx \frac1{n}-\frac1{2n^2}
$.

I'm stopping here
since I need sleep.

Comment: That's a clear thinking, But I think.$f''(x)$ shouldn't appear.Because,we don't know $f'(x)$ is derivable or not.

Comment: That equation gives f' in terms of f. Since f is derivable, so is f'. By induction,  all derivatives of f exist. That equation can be used to find a power series for f.

Comment: Oh,You are right. And..how to do next..Have you got idea? thank you.

Comment: I do. See my new answer.